# Bind Object from Button to Property in ViewModel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

what I a trying to do here is bind the object that the button contains to a property in my ViewModel in order to use it, but cannot resolve my problem. I read about Tag property but couldn't fully understand how it binds and how can I use it.

My Buttons:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
        <GroupBox>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Button x:Name="Button"
                        FontSize="10"
                        Height="80" Width="80"
                        Content="{Binding Name}"
                </Button>
           </WrapPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I populate my buttons with data from ObservableCollection

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="OrderButtons"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="OrderButtons1"
                  Margin="3">
            <ItemsControl   
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OrderTemplate}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ObservableCollectionWithData}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </WrapPanel>
```

My ViewModel

```
public class OrderViewModel : ObservableCollection<Order>
{
    public Item OrderItem{ get; set; }

    public OrderViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

What should I do in order to bind my Button, which contains object from type Item(my custom class) to OrderItem property of the my ViewModel?

What I tried is:

```
  <Button x:Name="OrderButton"
                        FontSize="10"
                        Height="80" Width="80"
                        Content="{Binding Name}"
                        Tag="{Binding OrderItem, Source={StaticResource OrderViewModel}}"
                </Button>
```

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors for your itemscontrol?

Comment: No errors at all, I run my app and everything is smooth until I click the button and with a Command try to see if it binds the object correctly. What I removed from the button in the source is a command, which triggers MessageBox and try to print in it OrderItem.Name to see if correctly binds. What it does is it fires a message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Which means that OrderItem is empty.

Comment: BTW Binding errors aren't like exceptions, they're printed to the output.

Comment: Hello again. I was able to bind my buttons with a ObservableCollection property in my ViewModel, but my problem now is how to know which button is clicked, so I can use the object which is bound to the exact button. I already use my CommandParameter to send List of information from another control, so I cannot use it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're creating a 'selector'; i.e. when the button is clicked, you want the OrderItem property of the view model to contain the 'Item' that was clicked.

If this is the case, you'd be better off using a ListBox as follows:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ObservableCollectionWithData}}" SelectedItem="{Binding OrderItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You should also then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "when the button is clicked, you want the OrderItem property of the view model to contain the 'Item' that was clicked". That is exactly what I am trying to do here, but I want to stick with the button because I need to use commands.

Comment: You answer helps, but I need to remodel it, when I am ready, I will update the question and set and answer.

Comment: May I ask why? Can you not call the command logic in the setter of the OrderItem property? I encourage the use of Commands but wonder why their use is imperative here.

Comment: Hello again. I was able to bind my buttons with a ObservableCollection property in my ViewModel, but my problem now is how to know which button is clicked, so I can use the object which is bound to the exact button. I already use my CommandParameter to send List of information from another control, so I cannot use it. Any ideas? Thanks!